# How would I report income from an employer that won't give me a 1099-NEC or W2?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I worked for an employer for around 5 months receiving a total of $39,000. When I started working with them, I signed a job offer but that was it. All payments were made via. wire transfer.

Since leaving the employer, I've yet to receive either a W-2 or a 1099-NEC. I obviously still need to report these earnings when filing my tax paperwork, but I'm not sure how I go about filing it if I've not received either a 1099-NEC or a W-2.

Comment: Have you contacted the employer about this? Maybe it's an error in their system or the form just got lost in the mail.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus I've reached out about 15 times over both SMS and Email requesting both the tax documents as well as the last paycheck i was never paid. They still owe me around $7,500 on top of not giving me this tax paperwork.

Comment: And what has been their excuse? Sounds like a great opportunity for a lawsuit.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus Well they haven't responded to me, so I don't know what their excuse is lol

Comment: Besides SMS and e-mail, have you actually called?

Comment: Yes, I've tried calling them as well without answer.The only medium I haven't attempted is postage.

Comment: Are they located somewhere you can easily get to, and see them in person?

Comment: It occurs to me--do they still exist?

Comment: The company was a small start up that was dissolved shortly after I left. The individual running it has successfully run and sold several companies in the past, so I wouldn't expect it to be beyond him to properly take care of employees. I had his direct contact info, and he is who I've been attempting to get in contact with (he was the only other individual in the organization).

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a pretty big problem.

Has the employer withheld payroll taxes? (Social Security, Medicare) Have you been considered an employee according to the State law or [the IRS guidance](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/independent-contractor-self-employed-or-employee)?

If you're considered a contractor according to the law/guidance, then report as if you've received 1099-NEC and pay the self-employment tax.

If you're considered an employee, then your employer should have paid payroll taxes (which include FICA, FUTA, State taxes and other mandatory payments), and should have reported them timely and properly on various forms, including W2. If they didn't - you can complain to your State labor board or other regulatory agency responsible for oversight of labor laws, and the IRS. The IRS instructions are at the same link I posted above.

Comment: Based on the number that was provided in the job offer i signed, they were paying me without deducting taxes from it. I assumed this just meant I was supposed to pay taxes on in myself. But i wasn't technically a contracted employee, the only paperwork I ever signed with them was a job offer.

Comment: @NathanF. you're responsible for your income taxes, but if you're an **employee** then the employer is responsible for payroll taxes. That's the law. What piece of paper you signed doesn't matter, what matters is what you have *factually* been doing. Read the IRS site carefully, and check your own State laws.

Comment: @NathanF. fyi - employers messing with payroll taxes is a huge action target for the IRS. Just saying...

Comment: Just to make sure it's clear, it's the employer that's done wrong here in the IRS's eyes, not you. You definitely have some obligations, whether or not the employer cooperates, but they're the ones who have royally screwed the pooch if they were supposed to be paying payroll taxes and didn't do so.

Comment: How come no one is asking the obvious question: "did you contact the employer and if so, what did they say?" The OP only mentions that he's "yet to receive" the forms. For all we know they could have just gotten lost in the mail.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus honestly, don't see how that is relevant. The burden of proof is on the employer. From what it sounds, the OP never got any payslips and the OP didn't mention submitting invoices either, so it's quite fishy no matter how you look at it.

Comment: @littleadv It is fishy, but getting in touch with the employer to get more information is absolutely relevant. It should be, in fact, step number one.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus sounds like the OP did that. Going there in person may not be a reasonable expectation. Honestly, payments with wire transfer already raise some red flags for me...

Comment: @littleadv If reasonably able to, the OP should try to meet them in person. If after that he still can't get in touch with them, then he has already exhausted all options and should consider legal recourse, not because of the missing W-2, but because of the $7,500 they owe him, and the potentially missing payroll tax contributions.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus I'd advise against in-person meetings in this situation. This can lead to either violence against the OP or accusations of OP's violence, or any other improprieties that may adversely affect the legal proceeds later. Generally confronting criminals is dangerous and ill-advised.

Comment: @littleadv We're only talking about a missing paycheck and W-2 here, and we still don't even know for sure if the employer intentionally did anything wrong. I'd leave it to the OP to use some common sense, but unless we're talking about the Sinaloa cartel, I'm sure it's safe to try to reach them in person after emails and phone calls have failed. Let's not lose our heads and keep things in perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can report income without having a 1099.  So long as you know how much money you got you can go ahead and file.

While it seems they painted a big IRS target on their posterior note that it's on them, not on you.

Answer (score 1):

If they should have given you a W-2 and did not, the IRS has a page with instructions on what to do: https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc154 Basically, notify the IRS and use form 4852 to report the income that would have been on a W-2.

I'm not sure about not getting a 1099. Independent contractors and small businesses often collect income not reported on a 1099, and there's a place on the forms to say "income reported on 1099" and "income not reported on 1099", so I'd say just put it down as income not reported on a 1099. If the employer should have given you a 1099 and didn't, they're subject to fines, but that's not your problem.

My guess is that what's going on is that the employer is trying to avoid paying employment-related taxes. But it's also possible they're just disorganized.

Comment: There's no different places on the forms (except 1099-PATR for cooperatives on schedule F, and the de-minimis case for reported LTCG distributions to bypass schedule D), although tax-prep software often _inputs_ information separately from 109X's and other sources, then combines them.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Oh, could be. It's been a while since I've filled out the forms by hand. I usually get a copy of the  paper form and check the paper entry when answering a question like this. This time I was lazy and did not. Yeah, H&R block software asks for them separately, and when you give the non-1099 number, it asks if you're sure you didn't already report this as 1099.